# onSharedPreferenceChanged is causing a stack overflow on some Android devices

Tags: android, recursion, overflow, sharedpreferences

I've just released my first live wallpaper for android.  I bug tested it on my phone and several friends phones without finding any problems, but apparently on some devices it's getting stuck in a recursive loop and causing a stack overflow error when the user tries to change settings.

I believe the problem is occurring because I have certain "theme" settings which need to change several other persisted values.  For example one theme will set a default color, speed, background, etc. It seems that when I persist these values programmatically with Editor.commit(), it's calling onSharedPreferenceChanged again, and again, and again...

Since this is a live wallpaper, I have a preview running behind the transparent preference screen, and I need it to reflect the settings changes as they're made.  I also need the sliders/color pickers/list preferences to reflect changes made both by the user directly, and programmatically when a "theme" is selected.  The easiest way to do this seemed to be to change them with a preference editor in onSharedPreferenceChanged, and indeed, this works on many devices.

What can I do to make it work on all devices?

Here's the relevant code:

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) 
{


    if(key != null)
    {

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

     hue = prefs.getInt("color", 0);
     BG_COLOR = prefs.getInt("background_color", 0);

//etc...



   if(key.matches("plasma_set"))
   {

       plasmaAtlasName = atlasName;
       editor.putString("atlasName", atlasName);

       //load each bolt set with defalut values

       if(plasmaAtlasName.equals("plasmaAtlas11"))
       {
           hue = 180;
           editor.putInt("speed", 10);
           editor.putInt("bolt_density", 2);
           BG_COLOR = 0;
           editor.putInt("background_color", BG_COLOR);
           editor.putInt("color", hue);
       }

       if(plasmaAtlasName.equals("plasmaAtlas9"))
       {
           hue = 330;
           editor.putInt("speed", 10);
           editor.putInt("bolt_density", 2);
           BG_COLOR = 0;
           editor.putInt("background_color", BG_COLOR);
           editor.putInt("color", hue);

       }

   //etc...
}

editor.commit();
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.  It was a simple matter of unregistering the listener before calling Editor.commit() and then registering it again afterward.

Comment: Could you give some example?